# Undefined method error with Rails has_one association (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I am attempting to access the methods of an associated model in the view, but getting an undefined method error

> undefined method `cpt_code' for Procedure:0x007fe7b55518e8

.  Thanks for your help!

index view:

```
<% @actuals.each do |actual| %>
  <% if actual.procedures.present? %>
    <% actual.procedures.each do |procedure| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= procedure.cpt_code.id %></td>
       <td><%= procedure.description %></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def index
    @actuals = Actual.all
  end
```

Models:

```
class Actual < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :actual_procedures, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :procedures, through: :actual_procedures

class ActualProcedure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :procedure
  belongs_to :actual
end

class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :actual_procedures
  has_many :actuals, through: :actual_procedures
end

class CptCode < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :procedure
```

Procedures in schema:

```
  create_table "procedures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "cpt_code_id"
    t.string "code"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["cpt_code_id"], name: "index_procedures_on_cpt_code_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `cpt_code' for Procedure:0x007fe7b55518e8

<s>You don't have `cpt_code` in `procedures` table. Perhaps you meant `cpt_code_id`.</s>

**Update:**

Actual reason is you didn't defined association for `cpt_code` in `Procedure` model

```
class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :actual_procedures
  has_many :actuals, through: :actual_procedures
  belongs_to :cpt_code # you should have this
end
```